# How to prove that there is No solution

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers, sums-of-squares, pell-type-equations

Let $d$ be a square-free positive integer $d>1$. Then there are no integers $x,y,z,t,a,b,c$ with $x\neq \pm z$, and $xt-yz\neq 0$ such that:

$$\begin{cases} x^2+y^2=a^2 d \\ z^2+t^2=b^2 d \\ (x-z)^2+(y-t)^2=c^2d\end{cases}$$

I have proved that $d\equiv 1\pmod 4$, but nothing more...

Comment: You can imagine the coefficient $d$ as the sum of the squares. We use the following formula.  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1051335_pythagorean_triple  This will reduce the system of three equations a system of two equations. Her and must be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be an arbitrary integer, and take $y=a=x$, $z=t=b=1$, $c=x-1$ and $d=2$. Then
$$\begin{cases} x^2+y^2=2x^2=a^2 d \\ z^2+t^2=1^2+1^2=b^2 d \\ (x-z)^2+(y-t)^2=2(x-1)^2=c^2d.\end{cases}$$
So we can choose $x\neq \pm z=\pm 1$.

Comment: Yes, this is obvious. I have modified the statement. Thanks!